# How to add housenumber in nominatim API in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

The Nominatim [API](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/) states

'street= '

It implies that there is a space between `<housenumber>` and `<streetname>`.
However, when I try to enter a space in the URL

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=berlin&street=skalitzerstrasse 9&format=json
```

I get an error (understandable).

How to properly add the housenumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's better to prefix the housenumber and than you just urlencode the space like:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city=berlin&street=142%20skalitzer%20straße&format=json
```

You'll also have only the street as a response if a housenumber (like 9) is not present or mapped, that's why I have chosen a different housenumber as an example.